# small Time Series Analysis

Tags: r, time-series, prediction, arima, forecast

I need to make a prediction for the next 2 years. However, I have a very small amount of Data. 
Data:

```
   structure(list(BelegDat = structure(c(16801, 16832, 16861, 16892, 
    16922, 16953, 16983, 17014, 17045, 17075, 17106, 17136, 17167, 
    17198, 17226, 17257, 17287, 17318, 17348, 17379, 17410, 17440, 
    17471, 17501, 17532, 17563, 17591, 17622, 17652, 17683, 17713, 
    17744, 17775, 17805, 17836, 17866, 17897, 17928, 17956, 17987, 
    18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 18170, 18201, 18231), class = "Date"), 
        Value = c(37, 28, 37, 47, 37, 28, 37, 37, 19, 37, 37, 28, 
        40, 30, 40, 50, 40, 30, 40, 40, 20, 40, 40, 30, 30, 40, 30, 
        30, 40, 30, 30, 50, 30, 50, 20, 20, 60, 20, 60, 40, 20, 10, 
        40, 20, 20, 10, 44, 33)), row.names = c(NA, -48L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am using ARIMA:

```
myts <- ts(df_ready[,2], start=c(2016,01), end=c(2019,12), frequency = 12)

fit <- auto.arima(myts)

pred <- forecast(fit, 24) # next 2 years (24 Months)
plot(pred)
```

> My output: 
>   [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWBn7.png)

Could you, please, show me my mistake / suggest some other way how this prediction can be done?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you think It's wrong? Because the forecasts are stationary? Also can you please share a reproducible example of your data?

Comment: I think that forecast is wrong, because it does not capture any seasonality, it is just a straight line. 
Data which I used is the same as in the question. Or are you talking about the csv file ?

Comment: Just do `dput(your_dataframe)` and copy/paste the result in your question

Comment: thank you for the info, have just changed

Comment: @IvanMatoshchuk The data you show does not support any evidence of seasonality. An ARIMA(0,0,0) model is the "best" fit to your data; in other words, your data resemble white noise (that was shifted by an offset). Yet in other words, your data `y_i` are consistent with `y_i ~ N(offset, sigma^2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an argument in `auto.arima` called `D`. We need to set it to `1` in order to force arima to use a seasonal model. In this case,

```
m1 <- ts(df$Value, start = min(df$BelegDat), frequency = 12)
autoplot(forecast(auto.arima(m1, D = 1), 24))
```

which gives,

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! 
Could you, please, suggest some other algorithms, which can be useful for this data ?

Comment: I would recommend you explore package `forecast`. It was built by Rob Hyndman. [His book](https://otexts.com/fpp2/) is also perfect for giving you some insides to forecasting data and all examples are in R, utilizing, among others, his libraries

Comment: I would be **very careful** with interpreting those forecasts! Your data resemble (mean-shifted) white noise (which is what the output of `auto.arima` tells you). There is no (data-derived) evidence that there is a/any seasonality effect (nor is there evidence for any non-seasonal MA/AR effect).

Comment: @MauritsEvers Yes, I know. That is why I commented asking why he thinks the forecasts are wrong because of no seasonality. The main purpose of my answer is to showcase the seasonality argument of auto.arima and not revise OPs concept of how they approach it.

Comment: No worries Sotos. This was more meant as a comment to @IvanMatoshchuk. I've seen people with no or little formal training in stats over/mis-interpret statistical analyses time and time again, especially when they have a "clear" goal/outcome in mind. That's not necessarily what OP is doing, but IMO it's important to emphasise that this particular case is forecasting based on white noise.

Comment: @MauritsEvers yes, I get what you are saying and I 've seen people make such interpretations. I agree with your approach of naive (as per seasonality) forecasts on a white noise signal

Comment: @MauritsEvers and Sotos
thank you for the feedback. I completely agree with you both, I should enhance my knowledge of time series analysis. 
Some "good-looking" output was needed for this task, clearly, it would not be considered as a worthy forecast.

Answer (score 1):

Your data do not support any evidence of seasonality; your data are consistent with white noise shifted by an offset.

Forcing a specific SARIMA structure and then using that to forecast based on your white noise data is very dangerous.

To demonstrate, let's turn things around and generate white noise data that are shifted by the same offset and that have the same variance as your sample data. Keep in mind that this is **white noise by design**.

```r
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2018)
ts <- ts(
    rnorm(48, mean = 33.8750, sd = 11.15796),
    start = c(2016, 1), frequency = 12)
autoplot(ts) + theme_minimal()
```

[image]

We now fit a SARIMA(0, 0, 0)(0, 1, 0)<sub>12</sub> model to the data.

```r
fit <- arima(ts, order = c(0, 0 , 0), seasonal = list(order = c(0, 1, 0), period = 12))
fit
#
#Call:
#arima(x = ts, order = c(0, 0, 0), seasonal = list(order = c(0, 1, 0), period = 12))
#
#
#sigma^2 estimated as 283:  log likelihood = -152.7,  aic = 307.39
```

Again, keep in mind that data was generated from ARIMA(0,0,0) = SARIMA(0,0,0)(0,0,0), i.e. a white-noise model.

We now use `fit` to forecast

```r
autoplot(forecast(ts, h = 24, model = fit)) + theme_minimal()
```

So what we've done here is to forecast based on white noise data assuming a non-existent seasonality effect.

[image]

Yes, you can do that without raising any warnings/flags within `forecast`. And no, these forecasts will not be meaningful.